# How to avoid circular dependency

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I got a hobby project I am working on in ASP Core 2.0 in which I am encountering some circular dependencies which I cannot figure out how to solve.

My solution (lets call it Hobby) has two ASP Core projects in it:

- `IdentityProvider` which has Identity Server 4 with ASP Core Identity and EF Core
- `HobbyAPI` which is consumed by front end angular application secured by the IdentityProvider

Now `HobbyAPI` contains an Entity called `BaseStats` which I need to reference in one of view model classes that is located in `IdentityProvider` project.

Unfortunately it doesn't allow me to use `HoobyAPI.Entities.BaseStats` entity in the `IdentityProvider` project as it claims it is a circular dependency.

What solution can I implement that avoids circular dependencies?

Comment: You should move your models to a separate project, e.g. `Hobby.BusinessLogic` or `Hobby.Models`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a third project and reference it from both existing projects.

Some bad ascii structure illustration:

```
    ModelProject
    + contains BaseStats
     ^                  ^
     |                  |
     |                  |
IdentityProvider  <--  HobbyAPI
+ used BaseStats       + uses BaseStats
                       + uses IdentityProvider (or was it the other way around?)
```

Comment: I'll give this a go, should this be a shared .net library project or just blank asp core project?

Comment: @Aeseir the `ModelProject` should be a .Net class library

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a go in about hour, will let you know how i go

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help. For simple classes yes it does wonders, but once complexity ramped up cascade problems started occuring.

Comment: @Aeseir if you update the question with an example structure, I can look at it again. For the question asked, this would be a solution, so if the question is over-simplified that needs to be fixed first.

Comment: I think your solution works in principle of question. I think the problem is since im dependant on number of nuget packages, i have to make sure the shared library can consume these nuget packages